# How to set mongodb settings, like mongodb.debug in php.ini file?

Tags: php, mongodb

How to set mongodb settings, like mongodb.debug  in php.ini file?

For example, here [ http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.configuration.php#ini.mongodb.debug ] is described setting mongodb.debug   with values "" /    PHP_INI_ALL     .

How to set it in php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in the same file `extension=mongodb.so` is being declared, in my case, this file was `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mongodb.ini`

```
extension=mongodb.so
mongodb.debug="/var/log/php-fpm.mongodb-debug.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[mongodb]
debug = stderr
```

The first line opens a new section and the following line is a configuration option in this section. This is very common for `ini` files.